Update Contact (MC REST API) does upsert actually
This is regarding Update Contact REST API call.
Although not mentioned in the documentation, it appears the call actually creates new contacts in case contactKey parameter value is not found.
Any advice how to avoid that?
Thanks.
Barak

If indeed true, then don't call Update on a non-existing contactKey.

identigral -
this is a possible scenario we must handle. Any reference to an API call for simply making sure a contactKey exists in all contacts (before initiating the Update Contact call)? Couldn't find something like that in the docs.

All Subscribers is the most reliable source, only SOAP API is available. Contacts with contactKey as the identifier can be had via REST. See this Q&A on contacts vs subscribers et al.
